# Download an existing report with facbook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

how to export existing report ? like when you export report from ads manager can i use the selected_report_id like in the url

```
https://business.facebook.com/adsmanager/reporting/view?act=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&business_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&event_source=CLICK_REPORTS_FROM_SIDE_NAV&selected_report_id=6138855090860
```

i have use this reqest :

```
https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report/?report_run_id=<REPORT_RUN_ID>&name=<REPORT_FILE_NAME>&format=csv&access_token=<FACEBOOK_API_KEY>
```

but it send me an html page in result

i was usig this code from [GitHub](https://github.com/fredericharnois/facebook-ads-reporting-google-apps-script)

can you help me